# Eigenstates for $\vec{L}^2, L_z, L_x$ and $L_y$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, commutator, linear-algebra, observables

I am asked to find states $|j,m\rangle$ that are simultaneously eigenstates for $\vec{L}^2, L_z, L_x$ and $L_y$. I know that the $L_i$ operators do not commute and hence you cannot have a state $|\phi\rangle$ that is common to $L_i$ and $L_j$ because that would imply that

$$[L_i,L_j] |\phi\rangle= \vec{0}$$

Since $\vec{0}$ is not an eigenvector by definition, I believe that you cannot have any common eigenstates between $L_i$ and $L_j$. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you know what is the requirement for operators to have common eigenstates? I don't give the answer because this would invalidate this home work question.

Comment: I suspect that you have misunderstood what is being asked.

Comment: @my2cts it’s not actually a HW question. I’m self-studying a course.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if two observables do not commute, then there exists no common eigenbasis. However, this in general does not mean that there are no states which are eigenstates of both operators.

For your specific example: You could try to express $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$ in terms of the ladder operators $\hat{L}_+ $ and $\hat{L}_-$. Applying $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$  to $|l,m\rangle$ and require them to be eigenstates then yields conditions on $l$ and $m$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only state that is a simultaneous eigenstate of ${L}^2, L_z, L_x$ and $L_y$ is $|l=0, m=0 \rangle$ (thus the ground state of the Hydrogen atom) with eigenvalue $0$ for all the concerned observables. As expected, this doesn't form an orthonormal basis by itself.

It is easy enough to see why this is the only such state in existence. The states $|l,m \rangle$ are by definition the simultaneous eigenstates of ${L}^2\text{ and } L_z.$ Now, we need to find specific values of $l$ and $m$ for which these states are also eigenstates of both the $L_x$ and $L_y$ operator. At first site, this looks impossible as $L_x$ or $L_y$ are linear combinations of the two ladder operators $L_{+}$ and  $L_{-}$ which change the value of $m$ by one and keeps the value of $j$ the same; thereby producing a completely different state. The only exception is when the state is such that both the ladder operators annihilate it. This is only possible for the state with $|l=0,m=0\rangle$.